# How can I redirect to the same page and keep textbox values in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, textbox

I have a scenario where I use a popup to select a search item before sending it to the previous (parent) window.

I would like to send the search value that the user clicked in the popup back to the parent window using a redirect and sending the value through the querystring. I know that obviously that will reload the page.

How can I keep or re-assign those values from before back to the page when it loads up again?

The reason I am doing this by the way instead of using JS to send back the values is that the popup and parent windows can be re-useable across many different scenarious with different amounts of data being load transfered so I want to keep the flexibility of the code-behind.

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from the sounds of it using Viewstate would work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ViewState["SomeInformation"] != null)
        NameLabel.Text = ViewState["SomeInformation"].ToString();
    else
        NameLabel.Text = "Not set yet...";
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of viewstate, do I have to populate that with the textbox values at some point?

Comment: Hi coonersz. Yes you would. ViewState["SomeInformation"] = MyValue;

Comment: I'm not fully sure how your application works. use an event when your text box loses focus and store it in the view state. would be one way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx There could be a better solution but that should work

Comment: I'm not sure it would work because the page could be refreshed at any time and how can I check the focus from the code behind in order to set the viewstate?

Comment: if the page is being refreshed store the values on the page unload event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx that is the last thing that will happen on the page. Then you can store the values as showed above in the viewstate